# Multiple condition on rowStyleClass in dtata table PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, background, datatable, rows

I am using primefaces for the first time in my web project and colored my data table rows dynamically using rowStyleClass like

`rowStyleClass="#{alar.severity eq 'Major' ? 'major' : null}"`
But is there any way to check multiple conditions in the rowStyleClass?
I want to check the severities Major, Minor, and Normal. How can I execute multiple conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In think in your case and in general if you use the lower case severity as row class and you dont want to exclude any severities, the following should do the trick:

```
rowStyleClass="#{not empty alar.severity ? alar.severity.toLowerCase() : null}"
```

Another more extensible and more readable solution would be to define a bean-method which takes `alar` as parameter and returns the styleclass:

```
public String alarStyleClass(Alar alar) {
    if(alar.severity.equals("Major")) return "major";
    if(alar.severity.equals("Minor")) return "minor";
    if(alar.severity.equals("Normal")) return "normal";
    return null;
}
```

And for the `rowStyleClass`:

```
rowStyleClass="#{bean.alarStyleClass(alar)}"
```

The last possible solution that comes to my mind would be to do all the checks directly in the `rowStyleClass`-attribute:

```
rowStyleClass="#{alar.severity eq 'Major' ? 'major' : 
                 alar.severity eq 'Minor' ? 'minor' :
                 alar.severity eq 'Normal' ? 'normal' :
                 null}"
```

Comment: I understand eq is for equal, but what is this language ? What is the other operator ? I search superior than, >. I have seen on the Web I can use le but I don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 3):

Just cascade the conditions:

```
rowStyleClass="#{alar.severity eq 'Major'  ? 'major'  : 
                (alar.severity eq 'Normal' ? 'normal' : 
                (alar.severity eq 'Minor'  ? 'minor' : null))}">
```

But it can get unclear fast, so don't cascade too often.